# Function-based Index using Substr and Instr

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I have created a query doing this in **ORACLE**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)) AS first_word, COUNT(*) AS word_count 
FROM FILM 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)) 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

Results after running: 
`539 rows selected. Elapsed: 00:00:00.22`

I need to improve the performance of this and created a `function-based index` as so:

```
CREATE INDEX INDX_FIRSTWRD ON FILM(SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)));
```

After running the same query at the top of this post, I still get the same performance:
`539 rows selected. Elapsed: 00:00:00.22`

Is the index not being applied or overwritten or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help you could provide. :)

EDIT:

```
Execution Plan:
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2033354507

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      | 20000 |  2968K|   138   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |      | 20000 |  2968K|   138   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| FILM | 20000 |  2968K|   136   (0)| 00:00:02 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - filter(COUNT(*)>=20)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      0  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
    471  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
  14030  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    908  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
     37  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
    539  rows processed
```

Comment: Does the query plan show that the index is being used?  Since you need to read every row from the table (or the index), I wouldn't expect the index to be hugely beneficial unless the `film` table is substantially bigger than the index.

Comment: @JustinCave How do I show the query plan for that query because when I type EXPLAIN PLAN FOR in front of the query I just get the result Explained.

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus, run `set autotrace on` before running your statement.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @JustinCave - I have edited my original post with the execution plan. I am using Oracle 11g. Based on the execution plan, does that mean it isn't using the index?

Comment: You complain about a response time of 22 mili seconds???

Comment: @Wernfried - I have a larger data set, but I was testing with less data but even at that level there should be a difference in time. It looks as thought it's not using the index however and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I would like to explain a bit more to what @Justin said in first comment. See my answer.

Comment: If you hint the query to force the use of the index, does your query actually run faster?  Why should there be a difference in execution time between full scanning the table and full scanning the index?  It's possible that there might be a difference but it might be hard to detect when you're looking at something that only takes 2 tenths of a second.

Comment: +1 @Justin, I really doubt hinting would make any difference. I said that in my answer too. Unless, we are talking about some magnitudes, but OP's use case is too trivial to make a substantial effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value you're using for the index may be null - if there is no space in the title (i.e. it's a one-word title like "Jaws") then your `substr` evaluates to null. That probably isn't what you want, incidentally - you probably want the end position to be conditional on whether there is a space at all, but that's beyond the scope of the question. (And even if you correct that logic, Oracle may still not be able to trust that the result can't be null, even if the underlying column is not nullable). **Edit:** see below for more on using `nvl` to handle single-word titles.

Since nulls aren't included in indexes, the single-title rows won't be indexed. But you're asking for all rows, and Oracle knows the index doesn't hold all rows, so it can't use the index to fulfil the query - even if you add a hint telling it to, it has to ignore that hint.

The only time the index will be used is if you include a filter that references the indexed value too, and explicitly or implicitly exclude nulls, e.g.:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)) AS first_word, COUNT(*) AS word_count 
FROM FILM
WHERE SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)) 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

(which also probably isn't what you actually want).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf872/1) for queries with and without a filter, and with and without an index hint. (Click the 'execution plan' link against each result section to see whether it's doing a full table scan or a full index scan).

And [another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf872/2) showing that the index can't be used even with the filter if the filter still allows null values, again since they are not in the index.

---

Since SylvainLeroux brought it up, Oracle isn't quite clever enough to know the computed value can't be null if you `coalesce` it, even if the underlying column is not-null (as a [function-based index](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb164/2) or [as a virtual column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feced/1)). Possibly because there could be a lot of branches to evaluate. But it is clever enough if you use the simpler and proprietary `nvl` instead:

```
CREATE INDEX INDX_FIRSTWRD
ON FILM(NVL(SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)),title));

SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)),title) AS first_word,
  COUNT(*) AS word_count 
FROM FILM
GROUP BY NVL(SUBSTR(title,1,INSTR(title,' ',1,1)),title) 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

But only if `title` is defined as not-null. And `coalesce` does work if [the virtual column is *also* declared not-null](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/020cd4/1) (thanks Sylvain).

[SQL Fiddle with a function-based index](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac653/1) and [another with a virtual column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72a96f/1).

Comment: Great explanation! One question though: _"even if you correct that logic, Oracle may still not be able to trust that the result can't be null"_ Would Oracle be smart enough to understand that the result _couldn't_ be NULL when using `COALESCE(SUBSTR(...), title)` (assuming title `NOT NULL`) ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - good question, I can't test that right now, but I would expect so - as long as title is itself not-null as you say. I'll try to remember to check and update tomorrow.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - [apparently not](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb164/2). Nor [with a virtual column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feced/1). Ha, but it is clever enough with `nvl` instead of `coalesce`, [as an FBI](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac653/1) and [as a virtual column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72a96f/1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Oracle cannot guess, but works as expected with `COALESCE` when you manually specify the [virtual column as being `NOT NULL`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/020cd4/1).

Answer (score 0):

> 539 rows selected. Elapsed: 00:00:00.22

Do you really think you need to tune the query which returns 539 rows in **less than a second**? 220 milliseconds, precicely! ***Think about it.***

In your case, I think `CBO` does the best possible thing. And that is the reason it doesn't use the `index`. Because, to read `every row` from the table, using the index is an overhead. It needs to read the index and then do a `table access by rowid`. Probably, in your small table, it could read the entire table with less `IO` to fetch the data.

If the table is small enough to be in a single block, then, it just requires a `one IO` to fetch required data from `single block` with `full table scan`.

You can try to check the explain plan by hinting the query to use the index and see if anything really improves. Remember, you are trying unnecessarily to improve the performance of a query which executes in less than a second!

Comment: 0.22 seconds is 220 milliseconds, not 22.  In this case, since all the information the query needs would be in the index, I would expect that the optimizer would do a full scan on the index and ignore the table (no need for a `table access by rowid`).  That might not be meaningfully quicker than doing a full scan on the table, though, depending on the size of the rows in the `film` table.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Corrected now. I agree, table access by rowid would be much overhead. OP has not mentioned the total number of rows the table has. You have a good point about size of row, that would need multiple blocks to be involved. I just think that in OP's case, it is not more than a single `IO` to fetch required data from single block with `full table scan`.